# How to set a trigger in Apps Script to start from a specific time and end in a specific time

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, time, triggers

I have encountered this issue where I need to delete appointment times starting from 11:00AM to 09:00PM. Basically, the trigger should start at 11:00AM by deleting the times from the Google sheet. I did a few coding to create my own trigger because the app script doesn't provide that function. I did run it but there's no function from the starting trigger but the ending trigger works. The **"rowCompare3"** functions work fine but the trigger doesn't activate hence why I'm pretty confused about this please can someone guide me on this appreciate it Cheers!!

This is my code:

```
function setTrigger2(){
  // Create the trigger at 11:00 AM
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('rowCompare3')
    .timeBased()
    .atHour(11)
    .nearMinute(0)
    .everyDays(1)
    .create();

  // Create the trigger at 9:00 PM
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('stopTrigger')
    .timeBased()
    .atHour(21)
    .nearMinute(0)
    .everyDays(1)
    .create();
}

function stopTrigger() {
  // Get all triggers associated with the 'rowCompare3' function
  const triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(trigger => trigger.getHandlerFunction() === 'rowCompare3');

  // Delete all triggers associated with the 'rowCompare3' function
  triggers.forEach(trigger => ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(trigger));
}

This is the spreadsheet that I'm using for testing https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iumKtia-Rq27d6E1oXpvU_kNxRLrGF6tsfBogBCKMEs/edit#gid=0
```

```html
function rowCompare3(){
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var clearSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("TEST2");
  var numRows = 2; // Starting number of rows
  var numCols = 3; // Number of columns
  
  var rangeA1 = clearSheet.getRange("A1");
  var rangeA2 = clearSheet.getRange("A2");
  var dateA1 = rangeA1.getValue();
  var dateA2 = rangeA2.getValue();

  // Compare the dates in cells A1 and A2
  if (dateA2 > dateA1) {
    rangeA1.clearContent();
    rangeA1.setValue(dateA2); // Move the data in A2 to A1
  } else if (dateA1 > dateA2) {
    rangeA2.clearContent();
  }

  // Delete rows B2, B3, B4, etc.
  for (numRows = 2; numRows <= clearSheet.getLastRow(); numRows++) {
    clearSheet.deleteRow(numRows);
    if (numRows >= 2) { // Break the loop after 1 row has been deleted
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Some guidence on how to create the trigger

Comment: Please share an example of the script you wish to run.  AFAIK there is no script that can run from 0900 to 2300 without timing out.  If you are just interested in deleting events begin from 0900 to 2300 you can do a search for all of those events and they loop through them all to delete them.  It's not really clear to me what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry my fault the appointment times are every 30 mins between 1100 to 2100 so the code will stop when one row is deleted but will continue again after 30 mins it should within the mentioned time period .

Comment: @Cooper Thank you for the concern but I found a solution and came up with a new code that works well with triggers.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to come up with a different idea hence the appointment times should be deleted every 30 minutes.
So this is my code:

```js
function setTrigger() {
  var startTime = new Date();
  startTime.setHours(2); //Allows to set a preferable time to start
  startTime.setMinutes(30);
  startTime.setSeconds(0);

  var endTime = new Date();
  endTime.setHours(21); //Allows to set a preferable time to end
  endTime.setMinutes(0);
  endTime.setSeconds(0);

  var intervalMinutes = 30; //Works with a 30 Minutes interval 

  var currentTime = new Date();
  var nextRunTime = new Date();
  nextRunTime.setTime(Math.ceil(currentTime.getTime() / (intervalMinutes * 60 * 1000)) * (intervalMinutes * 60 * 1000));

  if (nextRunTime < startTime) {
    nextRunTime = startTime;
  }

  while (nextRunTime <= endTime) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('rowCompare3')
      .timeBased()
      .at(nextRunTime)
      .create();

    nextRunTime.setTime(nextRunTime.getTime() + (intervalMinutes * 60 * 1000));
  }
}
```